# Smoothness of a function

Tags: linear-algebra

what do you mean by the following statement :

The function f depends smoothly on the parameter t.

what are the various conditions for it to be true ? any resources where I can learn more about this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: For a simple example: Suppose $f: [0, 1] \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(t, x, y) \mapsto f(t, x, y)$. Then "$f$ depends smoothly on the parameter $t$" means "for all $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the function $g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(t) = f(t, x_0, y_0)$ is a smooth function". A function is called smooth if it is infinitely differentiable. If you want a better explanation, you need to tell us what is your definition of $f$.

Comment: the function is a logistic function f(x,k)=1/1(1+exp(-kx)) ; where k is a parameter